# How to make perl print HTML not raw code

Tags: html, perl

I have a .pl perl script on my website.
I want the code to print out as if it were a html page rather then perl page. My code is bellow, and bellow that highlight is what I 'see' when I visit the page. What I'd like to see when I visit the page is just 'Hello'. not all the tags.
(For purposes of being online I made the actual html code simply 'Hello' rather then the actual html that would be on my page. Although it server the same purpose...

What the .pl code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.10;
use CGI;

$q = CGI->new;

print $q->header("text/plain");

$html_template = qq{<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title></title>


</head>
    <body>

  <p>Hello</p>

    </body>
</html>
};

print $q->header;
print $html_template;
```

What It prints out when I visit the page:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title></title>


</head>
    <body>

  <p>Hello</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I want it to print out:

```
Hello
```

Comment: Do you realize you're printing `$q->header` twice?  Is that really what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `print $q->header("text/plain");`.

---

Your code boils down to

```
print $q->header("text/plain");
print $q->header;
print $html_template;
```

You send a header saying what follows is text data. The browser happily displays the remainder of the response (a second header and some HTML) as text data.

You should be doing

```
print $q->header("text/html");
print $html_template;
```

which is also achieved using

```
print $q->header;
print $html_template;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
print $q->header("text/plain");
```

If you tell the browser that you're sending text rather than HTML, sane browsers will believe you and display plain text.

Comment: Unless the browser is IE 8 or earlier, which treats `text/plain` as a request for content type autodetection.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line: print $q->header("text/plain");